# Timeline chart containing data from rows from different tabs possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm monitoring the performance my air-to-water heatpump in Google Sheets.
I have a water (flow/temp) meter, and a kWh-meter with an API from which I consume the data using a Google Apps Script.
This Google Apps Script writes the data to a Google Spreadsheet.
It automatically creates a new tab for each day, and each roughly 2 minutes a new row is populated with new data. It also creates a chart each day displaying the COP performance.

This is the result (which I find very useful so far):
[image]

However, each graph displays only the performance of one single day.
I'd like to be able to have one graph that displays the performance of all days. So a timeline graph that displays al days at once.
Is it possible to do this?

This is my GAS code to create the chart (area chart, but could be timeline chart as well):

```
function createChart(sheet) {
  var COPChart = sheet.newChart().asAreaChart()
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:A997"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("K1:K997"))
  .setTitle('COP vs time')
  .setXAxisTitle('t.o.d.')
  .setYAxisTitle('COP')
  .setPosition(4,21, 0, 0)
  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(COPChart);
}
```

Comment: can you just change the script to keep adding data to the same tab instead of a new tab per day?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility indeed. I like however that I can navigate trough the days without having to scroll down thousands and thousands lines of data. 
But, what can help is to add filters. Filtering on range of date works pretty well. And the chart will update based on the filter, so that might do the trick.

Comment: That's just what I was going to suggest. Good luck